# R how to add up elements of a vector step by step?

Tags: r, gis, spatial, raster

Regarding a timeseries of spatial data I am investigating on in R, I have got a question you could help me with!

I have got a huge rasterstack of daily data (for the years 2001 to 2015 = 14061 layers). Now I want to calculate the mean per year per pixel and store the result in a layer (result should be a rasterstack of 15 layers, one per year). The problem is, that I have to include the leap years into my study...

What I have got so far is the following:

```
ts_years <- seq.Date(as.Date("2001/01/01"), as.Date("2015/01/01"), by = "year")
# create a vector with 15 elements for 15 years

ts_years_length <- sapply(ts_years, yearDays)
# calculate number of days for the specific years

ts_years_length
[1] 365 365 365 366 365 365 365 366 365 365 365 366 365 365 365
```

Now I want to calculate the index - to chase the beginning and the end of every year in my rasterstack - to build the mean for every year with the help of that. Therefore I have to find out, how to solve the following problem:

```
year_2001 <- rasterstack[[1:365]]
year_2002 <- rasterstack[[366:731]]
year_2003 <- rasterstack[[732:1097]]
# ...and so on
```

To do so, I have to add up the created vector as following:

```
ts_years_length_index <- c(1, ts_years_length[1],
                           ts_years_length[1] + 1, ts_years_length[1] + 1 + ts_years_length[2])
# ...and so on
```

But since this is really a pain in the a**, it would be nice to do this in an automated way. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
require(lubridate)
ts_years <- seq.Date(as.Date("2001/01/01"), as.Date("2015/12/31"), by = "day")
lst<-list()
for (i in 2001:2015) lst[[as.character(i)]]<-which(year(ts_years)==i)
yearraster<-list()
for (i in 2001:2015) yearraster[[as.character(i)]]<-rasterstack[[lst[[as.character(i)]]]]
```

Instead of calculating the number of days in each year manually, this creates a vector of all the days in your time period, and then creates a list where each element is a vector of the indexes of all the days for that year. You can then use this list of index as the index for your rasterstack call, and place each rasterstack result into an element of a second list.

Comment: thanks a lot! this is solving the problem! Do you know whether it is possible to accept more answers as solution in stackoverflow or just one? Because nevertheless your answer solved my problem, I would like to know, how to write a loop, to add up a vector as I described (if it is possible over all in an elegant way)

Comment: This is the closest I can get: `x<-c(1,rbind(cumsum(ts_years_length),cumsum(ts_years_length)+1))[-(1+length(ts_years_length)*2)]` -- this will give you the vector you want. But it ain't pretty. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do this. (1) create a grouping index, and (2) use that index in `stackApply`

```
idx <- rep(1:length(ts_years_length), ts_years_length)
r <- stackApply(rasterstack, idx, mean)
```

See `?raster::stackApply` for an example with data